# C# repository and localizable entities

Tags: c#, dapper

In my app I have many localizable entities. Database structure for this entities 
is [image: here]. Types of PK in some tables may be differ (some of them is int, some is bigint). It depends on how much data will be stored in a table.
I use Dapper as ORM.

Now I have this solution (but something inside tells me that this solution is bad):

```
// ENTITY
public abstract class Entity
{
    public object Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity<TKey> : Entity
{
    public new TKey Id { get; set; }
}

// LOCALIZABLE ENTITY
public abstract class LocalizableEntity<TTranslation> : Entity
    where TTranslation : EntityTranslation
{
    public ICollection<TTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public abstract class LocalizableEntity<TKey, TTranslation> : Entity<TKey>
    where TTranslation : EntityTranslation
{
    public ICollection<TTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
}

// ENTITY TRANSLATION
public abstract class EntityTranslation
{
    public object LocalizableId { get; set; }

    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
}

public abstract class EntityTranslation<TKey> : EntityTranslation
{
    public new TKey LocalizableId { get; set; }
}

// REPOSITORIES

public class BaseRepository: IRepository, IDisposable
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; } 

    // ....
}

public abstract class BaseEntityRepository: BaseRepository
{
    protected IDbConnection Connection => _connection ?? (_connection = CreateDbConnection(GetConnectionStringValue(ConnectionString)));

    protected abstract IDbConnection CreateDbConnection(string connectionString);

    // SaveEntity<T>(T entity), DeleteEntity(object id)
}

public abstract class BaseEntityRepository<TEntity, TKey, TSearchOptions, TLoadOptions> : BaseEntityRepository
    where TEntity : Entity<TKey>
    where TSearchOptions : SearchOptions
    where TLoadOptions : LoadOptions
{
    // GetEntities(TSearchOptions sopts, TLoadOptions lopts), EntityCount(TSearchOptions) ...
}

public abstract class BaseLocalizableEntityRepository<TEntity, TKey, TEntityTranslation, TSearchOptions, TLoadOptions> : BaseEntityRepository<TEntity, TSearchOptions, TLoadOptions>
    where TEntity : Entity<TKey>
    where TEntityTranslation : EntityTranslation<TKey>
    where TSearchOptions : SearchOptions
    where TLoadOptions : LoadOptions
{
    // GetTranslations, SaveTranslation ...
}
```

Is it good or bad? If it is bad, how should I do it?

Comment: Is the built in localization that is done with `.resx` files an option for you? Or is the localization that you need highly customizable? i.e. the user has to write the translation.

Comment: @MichaelMairegger I need highly customizable localization.

Comment: One problem with this is collation. If you have different languages in one DB column you may have trouble sorting with the right collation for a given language, because the collation belongs to the column. I'm not aware of a solution for this. It would be nice to find one, because the alternatives all seem to involve dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

As you need highly customizable localization your solution is not so bad. I perform the same way if I need translation. But instead having a different table per entity-translation I have a unique table to which any entities that support translation reference to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Test_Translations
(
    Language char(10) NOT NULL,
    TextId int NOT NULL,
    Value text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Test_Translations_Language_TextId_pk PRIMARY KEY (Language, TextId)
);

CREATE TABLE Test_LocalizableStrings
(
    Id int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Test2_Test1Id_pk primary key
);

ALTER TABLE Test_Translations ADD FOREIGN KEY (TextId) REFERENCES Test_LocalizableStrings;
```

[image: Resulting Tables]

Then in the tables that need a translation support just create a reference key to Test_LocalizableStrings. At query time query for `TextId` and `Language`.